# Java and SQL Anywhere: No suitable driver found for jdbc:default:connection

Tags: java, jdbc, sqlanywhere

I wrote a simple Java (1.8) function which is stored and run on a SQL Anywhere database (17). It does some file processing with some SQL blob INSERT/UPDATE calls.

Since it runs on a database, the connection was done (as on other functions) like this:

```
Connection conn;
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:default:connection");
```

This worked fine across multiple functions and databases, until a client started having problems. When inspecting the server log, I found my exception printouts from try-catch statements:

> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:default:connection

Now here is the confusing part: it worked fine for weeks, nothing was changed on the server. Other clients don't have this problem. Did someone face something similar?

Comment: Have you try to install the driver ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/download-microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: This are for MS sql server, I'm using SQL Anywhere. Plus, the same code worked a few days ago, without installing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Well... judging by the logs, it turned out that the database had a forced shut down, like if power was cut. The problem started after that. Some files might got corrupted.